# Panoramic Stitching is not working properly

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-stitching, panoramas

I am trying to stitch two images together in which both images have different angles. Shown below:
[image]
[image]

As you can see, there are some overlaps. However, when I stitch them, I get the following:
[image]

I use the following algorithm:

- SIFT
- Lowe Ratio test
- Homography
- FlannBasedMatcher (RANSAC)
- Wrap Perspective

**Lower Ratio Test**

```
        if len(item) < 2:
            continue
        (left, right) = item
        if left.distance < 0.78 * right.distance:
            good.append(left)
```

**Homography**

```
# img_feature is an object containing the keypoints where 1 refer to image 1.

src_pts = np.float32([img_feature1.key_points[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2) 
    dst_pts = np.float32([img_feature2.key_points[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    # Defining the Homography parameters
    homog_method = cv2.RANSAC
    homog_reprojthres = 5
    homog_mask = None
    homog_max_iter = 2000
    homog_confidence = 0.995

    homog_matrix, mask = cv2.findHomography(
        dst_pts,
        src_pts,
        homog_method,
        homog_reprojthres,
        homog_mask,
        homog_max_iter,
        homog_confidence,
    )

    return homog_matrix, mask
```

**Flann Matcher**

```
def compute_flann_matcher_sift(des1, des2):
    """Computing the flann matchers"""
    # Defining the FlannMatcher parameters
    flann_index_kdtree = 0
    index_params = dict(algorithm=flann_index_kdtree, trees=5)
    search_params = dict(checks=50)
    # Set up the flannMatcher
    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

    # Get the matches
    matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
    return matches
```

**Wrap perspective**

```
def blend_image(img1, img2, homog_matrix):
    # Warp the image 2 (right) for image 1 (left)
    dst = cv2.warpPerspective(
        img2, homog_matrix, (img1.shape[1] + img2.shape[1], img1.shape[0])
    )

    # Concatenation
    dst[0 : img1.shape[0], 0 : img1.shape[1]] = img1
    return dst
```

Comment: What's wrong with the stitching?  For me it looks like it's stitched very well, although there was little overlap?

Comment: @Micka The building on the right is a bit distorted. I used the openCV stitcher class itself to see if I would achieve the same result and it was a proper stitch without distortion and I would like to do the same without using the stitcher class.

Comment: The distortion is from plane to plane transformation, which will always introduce distortions for a non-planar scene. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/d46/group__stitching.html for what happens in the high level stitching pipeline.

Comment: Have a look at this one as well. The distortion in the second-last image is what you need. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html

Comment: "Warp surface type is fisheye" and not sure about what wave correction horizontal does there.

Comment: Or even better a "cylindrical projection". Google for cylindrical projection panorama